# Issues with JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

So I am trying to correctly and fully javadoc comment this block of code but I dont know what all to do and what not to do. Thanks !

```
public double largerRoot (double a, double b, double c) throws Exception
{
    double discriminant;
    double root1;
    double root2;

    discriminant = Math.sqrt ( b * b - 4 * a * c );

    if ((discriminant < 0) || (a == 0))
    {
        throw (new Exception("Math Error"));
    }

    root1 = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);
    root2 = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);

    return Math.max(root1, root2);
    }
```

Comment: What have you found out so far? What have you tried? (It's hard to know where to start explaining here.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did your instructor teach you about JavaDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in eclipse, press `Alt + Shift + J`

else: google ([like this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html))

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer to the question. Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First: I would rename a b and c parameters with a name that speak.

Second: method/class description : always write javadoc with "Why" in mind.  I mean most of the dev write javadoc that explain what the code do...  this is kind of helpless since most of the programmer know how to read the code.  I always try to describe the class or method as why i did it and what purpose (contract) it should do.

Third: details about parameters is a must (null accepted or not, is there any range..etc)

Fourth: details about the return value.

fifth: reference : @see can be usefull to the javadoc user who want to know about a class you use inside your method.

Hope it help.